# Выбор значения из заранее определенной таблицы (БД)

Tags: база-данных

Есть таблица (см. картинку), содержащая поля "Type" и "Value". "Type" может быть улицей, районом или городом. Как сделать так, что если "Type" соответствует типу "Улица", то можно было бы выбрать конкретное значение ("Орджоникидзе", "Мичурина") только из определённого списка? Соответственно, если Type соответствует типу "Город", то можно было бы выбрать значение только из списка городов. Аналогично и для района.

И это проверялось бы не программно, а через БД. Вопрос - как это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш вопрос "в целом", для произвольной базы данных, при сохранении вашей архитектуры решен быть не может. Это можно было бы сделать например триггерами. Только триггера в стандартах SQL не оговорены, поэтому сильно зависят от СУБД

Comment: таблицы связаны по value? а он сквозной или для улицы и города может повторяться? В любом случае можно приджойнить к вашей таблице три других и в качестве условия присоединения указать соответствующее условие для type. Но определять сработавшую запись все равно придется программно: в коде программы смотрите на поле для улицы - если пустое, значит смотрите другое поле. Если нет ни одного непустого поля, значит такой записи не в нужной вам таблице

Comment: хотя не прав был - в select'е можно из трех столбцов выбрать не пустой. А "не пустым" будет только один, т.к. таблицы мы по типа делим. Т.е. можно одним запросом получить необходимые данные, но от лишних джойнов избавиться вроде нельзя. Хотя в вашем случае это сильно и не скажется, т.к. условие джойна будет сразу же отвергать записи из лишних таблиц

Comment: в моем случае количество таблиц не ограничено - кроме 3х таблиц - город, улица, район, могут быть еще десятки.